# Is 2312 a "post scarcity" society?

Tags: kim-stanley-robinson, energy, 2312

In a few places the book suggests that human civilization has moved to a [post scarcity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-scarcity_economy) stage. This seems to be corroborated by the extensive teraforming projects underway through out the Solar system, as well as the fact that massive aid to Earth is dispatched virtually without discussion and very little supervision.

In order for that to be possible, cheap and virtually limitless source of energy needs to be available, but the book does not seem to explain what that is.

**Am I missing something here? Is the world truly post-scarcity and if so what's the source of that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. In terms of energy production, there's a throwaway line about halfway through the novel that mentions that between 2130-2160, humanity acquired the ability to create stable fusion power. This is something that should, in theory result in the near-limitless production of electricity:

> **The Turnaround: 2130 to 2160.** Verteswandel (Shortback’s famous
>   “mutation of values”), followed by revolutions; strong AI;
>   self-replicating factories; terraforming of Mars begun; **fusion power**;
>   strong synthetic biology; climate modification efforts, including the
>   disastrous Little Ice Age of 2142–54; space elevators on Earth and
>   Mars; fast space propulsion; the space diaspora begun; the Mondragon
>   Accord signed.

As far as material needs are concerned, it appears that the age-old problem of distribution of scarce goods is still an issue in 2312:

> Going down in the cars were food (a crucial percentage of the total
>   needed), metals, manufactured goods, gases, and people. Going up were
>   people, manufactured goods, the substances common on Earth but rare in
>   space—these were many, including things animal, vegetable, and
>   mineral, but chiefly (by bulk) rare earths, wood, oil, and soil. The
>   totals came to quite a flow of physical mass up and down, all powered
>   by the counterbalanced forces of gravity and the rotation of the
>   Earth, with a bit of solar power to make up the difference.

Comment: I remember reading something that implied that, but was not sure what and where. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's heavily implied that the Mondragon economy allows for greater surpluses and greater efficiency in that world.  I didn't get the sense that it's entirely post-scarcity, the way the Federation is in *Star Trek*, I think it's just a very plentiful society, like modern America compared to 11th century Europe.

But we certainly see some poverty, or at least near-poverty, in 2312, for example on Venus.

Comment: When Swan and Wahram discussed the situation on Earth, they agree that there is no need for people to live on the edge, but it's just a way to control the masses and the depress wages. Maybe it's not even that, but just the old ways are too ingrained in the fabric of Earth without any good reason.

Comment: Star Trek is not post-scarcity-world. Brushing aside the problem it's impossible in physical world to achieve limitless resources, the S.T. economy is still market economy, but without money and standard human drives (incl. greed) redirected towards self-improvement (very generalized statement, I know).

Comment: @AcePL The entire ST universe isn't post-scarcity, but it's well-established that the Federation abolished poverty long ago.  "Lack of scarcity" doesn't mean "infinite resources," it just means "enough resources for everyone's needs."  The replicators do that in ST, which I was comparing to 2312, which does seem to have poverty and scarcity in some areas.

Comment: "Lack of scarcity" means exactly that: "Infinite resources", when talking about economy. If it's finite, then it is scarce. Can be very scarce, can be hardly scarce. But still scarce. It's much better to use term "elimination of poverty" (however this one is somewhat oxymoronic). And ST's replicators (and before them protein resequencers) run on energy - and on LOTS of it - which in ST-world is not unlimited. Abundant - yes, unlimited: no. Anyway, this is a fine point and I'm just being a stickler here (or grammar/terminal nazi, according to some ;-)

Comment: You can have infinite resources if you have unlimited energy. Each star produces virtually infinite amount of energy over infinite amount of time (it's estimated that the Sun will burn another 4 billion years, which for all intent and purposes is infinite amount of time from human perspective). If you can efficiently harness that energy (as the Vulcan and Mercurians are doing) you can achieve post scarcity. I'll try to dig  up the passage where that's mentioned in the book.

Comment: @AcePL Actually, if you're going to be a grammar Nazi, "scarcity" is defined as "the state of being scarce or in short supply; shortage."  That means that if you have *enough*, it's not scarce.  If you've got enough food to last you until you die, food is not scarce for you.  It doesn't matter if you have *infinite* food, you don't have a shortage and therefore you don't have scarcity.  So again, a post-scarcity world doesn't mean infinite supply, it means a world where no supply is inadequate to meet its demand.

Comment: @Nerrolken: Good point. By post-scarcity I mean that the material needs and wants of everyone can be fully satisfied. I'll even narrow down to original question to all reasonable wants and needs, owning a personal planet or something like that is out of the question.

Comment: @Nerrolken. Agreed - there is something to be said about different sciences and their "vocabulary". This has slightly different meaning in economy, as I always point out. And, to be completely truthful, term still applies: anything will be is shortage for someone in a given moment. For example: I'm in constant short supply of cider and/or donuts... Economically speaking "scarce" is everything, because, in fact, there is not enough for everyone. End of my rant, waiting for answer but will not reply as it is OT by now so much I can't see the OP's question. ;)